# What is the difference between allFile and allMarkdownRemark in gatsby

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

### allFile query :

```
query{
  allFile{
    edges{
      node{
        childMarkdownRemark{
          frontmatter{
            title
            desc
            link
          }
        }
        childImageSharp{
          fluid{
            srcSetWebp
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the above allFile query i get the below output

```
{
  "data": {
    "allFile": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "childMarkdownRemark": {
              "frontmatter": {
                "title": "Arrays in Javascript ",
                "desc": "I am hello i am the greatest lorem ipsum diut shit in the world of world",
                "link": null
              }
            },
            "childImageSharp": null
          }
        },
      }
```

### allMarkdown query:

```
query{
  allMarkdownRemark{
    edges{
      node{
        frontmatter{
          title
          desc
          link
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output for the above `allMarkdown` query is

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMarkdownRemark": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "frontmatter": {
              "title": "This is party react",
              "desc": "I am React GUyyyy ",
              "link": null
            }
          }
        },
```

*The output is limited to 1 item to save space for the question*

Is there any performance difference between `allFile` and `allMarkdownRemark` query

In `allFile` query, we can fetch *relative path*, *relative Directory* whereas allMarkdownRemark is limited to `fileAbsolutePath`

We have access to markdown in `allFile` query using *childMarkdownRemark* as you can see above.

In many YouTube tutorials, people use `allMarkdownRemark`. Is there any specific reason to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always depends on your filesystem and how it is set up.

The short answer is that `allFile` retrieves all kind of files (images, markdowns, JSONs, etc) set in your `gatsby-source-filesystem` while `allMarkdownRemark` only fetches the markdown files because a transformer plugin has previously created a specific node to do so.

`allMarkdownRemark`, of course, is more specific and has better performance, since you are querying only markdown files, not all kinds of files like `allFile` does. Regarding the filters, both are available (relative and absolute paths), use the GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) to test them.

---

### TL;DR

[`gatsby-source-filesystem`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/) creates file nodes from files. The various "transformer" plugins can transform file nodes into various other types of data e.g. `gatsby-transformer-json` transforms JSON files into JSON data nodes and `gatsby-transformer-remark` transforms markdown files into `MarkdownRemark` nodes from which you can query an HTML representation of the markdown.

Summarizing, `gatsby-source-filesystem` retrieves all types of files but must be set for each data folder to help other plugins to transform the file type into nodes to make them available to Gatsby and GraphQL.

`allMarkdownRemark`, is another transformer plugin that turns all markdown files (previously set in the `gatsby-source-filesystem`) into GraphQL nodes to make them available when you query a markdown file, allowing you to retrieve specific data from it.

Let's assume a filesystem like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
  },
},

{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `jsons`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/jsons/`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `markdowns`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/markdowns/`,
  },
},
```

If you leave the filesystem like this, `allFile` will retrieve JSONs as well as images and markdowns but you won't be able to query specific data from them, because there's no transformer plugin that has created a node, in addition, you will lose all the benefits of using combined plugins. If you add the `gatsby-transformer-remark` with the previous filesystem configuration like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-relative-images`,
      },
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 1200,
          withWebp: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

You are creating nodes for all markdown files and creating relative paths for images in there (`gatsby-remark-relative-images`), what saves you a few headaches and parses the images from it.

Comment: Thanks, Awesome stuff.  `gatsby-remark-relative-images` provides relative paths for the images  My doubt was that we dont get the _relative path_ to the markdown file in the `allMarkdownRemark`.

Comment: You can use GraphQL filters to build a query that matches your functionality despite not having a `relativePath`.